# pybind11 problems with directory structure

Tags: python, cmake, pip, linker-errors, pybind11

I'm trying to integrate pybind11 in my project with CMake. My structure is as follows:

```
foo
├───pybind11
├───src
    └─── __init.py__ (empty)
│   └─── mymodule.cpp
└─── __init.py__ (empty)
└───CMakeLists.txt
src
├───core
├───bar
├───baz
└───CMakeLists.txt
setup.py
CMakeLists.txt
```

In my foo project I need to link libraries in the core, bar and baz projects (that have all their own makefile), thus I've set up relative imports in my `foo/CmakeLists.txt` file, aside from the call to pybind11 obviously:

```
add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(foo src/mymodule.cpp)
set(CORE "../src/core")
...
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC
        core
        bar
        baz
        )
target_include_directories(pyceam
    PUBLIC  ${core}/include
    ...
)
```

inside I've copied the setup.py from [the official CMake example](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/blob/master/setup.py), the only line I've modified is in the setup call:

```
ext_modules=[CMakeExtension('foo', sourcedir='.')],
```

This installs correctly, but it does produce an empty module:

```
>>> import foo
>>> dir(foo)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

I figured that the problem was the `sourcedir` parameter, so I've tried two things but none of them worked:

1. move `setup.py` inside foo and call with `sourcedir='..'`
2. leave `setup.py` in the root dir and call with `sourcedir='./foo'`

and in both cases I get:

> 3>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'core.lib'

Can anybody please point me in the right direction in order to solve this issue?